# ArrayList doesn't store all elements from a database in Java

Tags: java, mysql

I have the following code. However, when I run it, I don't see in the `JTextArea` all the elements that are in my database, just the last one. But if I print out what I read from the database in that while loop, I get all of them, so I guess the problem is with the list of objects. Any suggestions of how I can solve this?

```
public class Muzica {
    static ArrayList <Melodii> lista=new ArrayList<Melodii>();
    static class Melodii
    {
        private String melodie;
        private String artist;
        private int an;
        public String getMelodie() {
            return melodie;
        }
        public void setMelodie(String melodie) {
            this.melodie = melodie;
        }
        public String getArtist() {
            return artist;
        }
        public void setArtist(String artist) {
            this.artist = artist;
        }
        public int getAn() {
            return an;
        }
        public void setAn(int an) {
            this.an = an;
        }

        public Melodii(String melodie, String artist, int an)
        {
            this.melodie=melodie;
            this.artist=artist;
            this.an=an;
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            return "Melodie: "+melodie+" Artist: "+artist+" An aparitie: "+an;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "root");
        Statement sql;
        sql=(Statement) con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs;
        rs=sql.executeQuery("select * from melodie");
        JFrame f=new JFrame("Melodii");
        f.setSize(300, 300);
        f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JTextArea t=new JTextArea();
        JButton b=new JButton("Stergere");
        b.setSize(30, 20);

        while(rs.next())
        {

            System.out.println(rs.getString("melodie")+rs.getString("artist")+rs.getInt("an"));
            Melodii m=new Melodii(rs.getString("melodie"), rs.getString("artist"), rs.getInt("an"));
            lista.add(m);
            for(int i=0; i<lista.size();i++)
            {
                t.setText(m.toString());
            }
        }


        f.add(t, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.add(b, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: because your `Melodii` class is *static*

Comment: You are not appending the text, you are setting each result read, which will be fast so you just see the last one. The method t.`setText(m.toString())` overrides previously set text. Try `t.append(m.toString());`, you may have to add some line breaks.

Comment: @CristinaMoroti Great... I have made an answer out of my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A problem in your code is this part:

```
while(rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getString("melodie") + rs.getString("artist") + rs.getInt("an"));
    Melodii m = new Melodii(rs.getString("melodie"), rs.getString("artist"), rs.getInt("an"));
    lista.add(m);

    for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
        t.setText(m.toString());
    }
}
```

You are creating a `Melodii` and adding it to `lista`, but then you loop through `lista` and override the previously set text in it.

I recommend not to loop through the entire list while the `ResultSet` has not been completely iterated. Move the `for` loop below the `while` loop and apply `append(m.toString())` instead of `setText(m.toString())`, like

```
while(rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getString("melodie") + rs.getString("artist") + rs.getInt("an"));
    Melodii m = new Melodii(rs.getString("melodie"), rs.getString("artist"), rs.getInt("an"));
    // just store all the results from the database, no need to iterate it at this point
    lista.add(m);
}
// instead, iterate the list afterwards and append the text
for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
    t.append(m.toString());
}
```